# JavaScript is not alerting the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

The JSON data from the URL given below  is like this:

```
{
   "datum":[
      {
         "id":"19",
         "song":"The Age of Worry",
         "path":"audio/age.mp3",
         "artist":"John Mayer",
         "album":"Born And Raised",
         "genre":"Blues-Rock",
         "year":"2012",
         "filename":"age",
         "extension":".mp3",
         "size":"6.1539077758789 MB ",
         "duration":"2:40",
         "downloads":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to alert the song name. the code below only alerts id but not the song. I couldn't figure out what's wrong here.

---

```
switch(id){
        case "1":
            alert(id);              
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/musicstore/search.php?media=audio&search_by=song&search_string=age", function(d) {
                 $.each(d.datum, function (i, res) {
                       alert(res.song);                     
                    });

            }); 

            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        }
```

Comment: For a greater chance for help, please post an example string of your json object.

Comment: It can be a crossdomain problem or smth else. Please add `console.log(d);` before $.each... and give us the firebug console output.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/eT4Na/2/

Comment: i'm askin to myself why didnt i use console.log().. hehe thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcfJq/). Your .each logic is working just fine assuming that your JSON data is coming back like your example says. So the problem must be in your PHP script returning the JSON.

Here is the simplified fiddle just to test your .each logic:

```
var jsonData = {"datum":[{"id":"19", "song":"The Age of Worry", "path":"audio/age.mp3", "artist":"John Mayer", "album":"Born And Raised", "genre":"Blues-Rock", "year":"2012", "filename":"age", "extension":".mp3", "size":"6.1539077758789 MB ", "duration":"2:40", "downloads":"0" }]};
$.each(jsonData.datum, function (i, res) {
    alert(res.song);                     
});​
```

Comment: @vinique, if this answer (or another) solves your problem mark it as Accepted. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

as far I know when you wanna alert json data it only shows like `[object Object]`, use console.log() instead, need firebug installed for that

Comment: or just use the console in Chrome : )

Comment: -1, because this doesn't really answer his question. He isn't alerting the java object, but just one attribute of the object which will output correctly.

Comment: thx @Varon.. very useful! By the way you missed safari :/ : (

Comment: @davidethell: He's definitely not alerting a Java object, no. If you're going to nitpick...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the response is valid, verify if the Content-Type header of the response from the server is set correctly to application/json

Comment: He is using a .each loop where res will be the value of a given key/value pair. So in his example res.song is valid syntax.